# How to stop this specific Audio Player when next Audio track plays (HTML5 + JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have multiple audio players on my page, and I am using **[this script](http://osvaldas.info/examples/audio-player-responsive-and-touch-friendly/audioplayer.js)**. They are all working fine but if you click a second player the first one continues to play. I've seen this question asked before but none of the answers are specific to this audio player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution of my problem, what I was doing before:

```
<script>
$( function()
{
    $( 'audio' ).audioPlayer();
});
</script>
```

What I'm doing now, tested with multiple browsers, it works:

```
<script>
$( function()
{
    $( 'audio' ).audioPlayer();
    var $audios = $('audio').on('play', function(){
        $audios.not(this).parents('.audioplayer-playing').find('.audioplayer-playpause').trigger('click');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get the player code right then you can pause/stop all the players with jQuery

```
$('.audioplayer-playpause').bind('click', function () {
  $('.audioplayer-playing').stop() #that will stop all the audioplayers which are currently playing audio
})
```

Comment: after adding the .audioplayer to DOM